# Value from one void function to another using pointers?

Tags: c

I've looked around but can't seem to find how to do this. I want the value of empty lines from `test2(int *f)` to be passed to `test1()` and be printed on the screen.

Variant 1 of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void test1();
void test2(int *f);
void test1(){
    int a;
    test2(&a);
    printf("%d \n", a);
}
void test2(int *f){
    char str[80];
    int lines, i,  emptylines=0;
    *f=emptylines;
    printf("Type a program here. Ctrl+Z and enter to stop.\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    while(gets(str)!=NULL && strcmp(str, "qq")) {
        for(i=0; i<strlen(str); i++){
            if(str[i]!='\n') lines=1;
        }
        if(!lines) emptylines++;
            lines=0;
    }
}
int main() {
    test1();
    return 0;
}
```

Variant 2 of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void test1();
void test2(int *f);
void test1(){
    int a;
    test2(&a);
    printf("%d \n", a);
}
void test2(int *f){
    char str[80], *p;
    int lines, emptylines=0;
    *f=emptylines;
    printf("Type a program here. Ctrl+Z and enter to stop.\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    while(gets(str)!=NULL && strcmp(str, "qq")) {
        p=str;
        lines=0;
        while(*p!='\0') {
            if(*p!=' ') {
                lines=1;
            }
            p++;
        }
        if(lines==0){
            emptylines++;
            lines=0;
        }
    }
}
int main() {
    test1();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have shown some code but have not described what issue you are having with them. Nor have you asked a question in relation to that code. So it is unclear what help you are requesting.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` invokes undefined behaviour. IOW: your code is broken by design. And `gets` is not part of the standard anymore, **never ever** use it!

Comment: This is not part of the first question and its another one  but whan to use instead of gets? scanf?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are putting `*f=emptylines` in the beginning of the function `void test2(int *f);` Then you calculate `emptylines` but this will not affect the value pointed-to by `f`.

You need to move that assignment `*f=emptylines` to the end of the function, just before returning and *after* having calculated `emptylines`

```
void test2(int *f){
    // stuff to calculate emptylines
    ....

    *f=emptylines; // at the end
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you write

```
*f = emptylines;
```

you are copying the value of emptylines into the space pointed to by f. Then when you update emptylines later, the value pointed to by f doesn't change because you made a copy.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using another variable `emptylines` just use the parameter `f` directly to compute the value. Though I'd give it a more descriptive value than `f`, something like `numEmptyLines`.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void test1();
void test2(int *numEmptyLines);
void test1(){
    int a;
    test2(&a);
    printf("%d \n", a);
}
void test2(int *numEmptyLines){
    char str[80];
    int lines, i;
    *numEmptyLines = 0;
    printf("Type a program here. Ctrl+Z and enter to stop.\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    while(gets(str)!=NULL && strcmp(str, "qq")) {
        for(i=0; i<strlen(str); i++){
                            if(str[i]!='\n') lines=1;
            }
            if(!lines) (*numEmptyLines)++;
                lines=0;
    }
}
int main() {
    test1();
    return 0;
}
```